# PyQt5 QMessageBox dialog closes main window from QPushButton but not QAction

Tags: python, pyqt5, signals-slots, qt-designer

Maybe a dumb question as I'm fairly new to PyQt but ...

I've generated a main window (QMainWindow) dialog from QtDesigner and added in signal/slot connections

```
self.dlg_ui.quit_button.clicked.connect(self.quit)
self.dlg_ui.actionQuit.triggered.connect(self.quit)
```

Note: quit_button is a QPushButton object and actionQuit is a QAction object

The slot self.quit opens a QtWidgets.QMessageBox.question dialog set up to offer file saving with a yes/no/cancel response but the dialog functions differently depending on where it was invoked from.

If invoked by actionQuit.triggered the dialog does what it should but if invoked by quit_button.clicked the dialog immediately closes the main window.

Since they're both invoking the same code I'm at a loss to know why the QPushButton.clicked signal causes the main window to close.

Any help in where to start looking would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: you must provide a [mcve]

Comment: Probably a glitch in the matrix. Lol, no honestly that just  sounds insane, we need to see more code

Comment: Ok, thanks.
I generated a simple MainWindow with a single menu item and a single button and built up single Python3 script to run it and everything works as as it should. Obviously I've done something stupid somewhere and I'll have to backtrack through my code. Since my code is modular I'll have to de-modularise it, debug it and re-modularise it when I can find out where the problem is.
If it turns out to produce useful information for others (a GOTCHA) I'll post my findings.

Answer (score -1):

After a fair amount of work, first creating a simple version of the ui where everything worked and then slowly adding code from the broken ui, bit by bit, I've finally worked out what generated the problem.

It turned out to be in the ui file created from QtDesigner - just about the last thing I added to the test script which, being automatically generated, I assumed the glitch was more likely to be in my own code.

In QtDesigner I'd added in connections between the button.clicked and action.triggered to MainWindow.close(). Once I deleted those links in QtDesigner and regenerated the ui file both the menu action and the button worked as they should.